# Extracting some strings with jq from Rapid7 OpenData website

Tags: string, bash, jq

I was wondering if someone had an idea how to extract with 'jq' the following strings; 'ip, port' from the input files available on Rapid7 opendata website:

[Rapid7 OpenData website](https://opendata.rapid7.com/sonar.https/)

Any help would be very appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? Jq has an extensive documentation, so you might have tried something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Download the JSON from Rapid7 OpenData

```
$ wget https://opendata.rapid7.com/sonar.https/2020-07-26-1595771130-https_get_50880.json.gz
```

#### Extract 'ip' and 'port' fields

```
$ zcat 2020-07-26-1595771130-https_get_50880.json.gz | jq '.ip,.port' | head
"73.71.198.224"
50880
"3.228.14.207"
50880
"175.139.245.229"
50880
"162.208.16.163"
50880
"58.58.213.88"
50880
```

#### Extract fields in the form 'ip:port'

```
zcat 2020-07-26-1595771130-https_get_50880.json.gz | jq -r '"\(.ip):\(.port)"' | head
73.71.198.224:50880
3.228.14.207:50880
175.139.245.229:50880
162.208.16.163:50880
58.58.213.88:50880
18.130.113.90:50880
54.216.22.17:50880
15.236.60.123:50880
77.54.234.109:50880
71.37.173.187:50880
```

Thanks to [@peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak) for the improvement!

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!!! I will search how to make this output into one line like this:

`175.139.245.229:50880
162.208.16.163:50880`

Once found, I will update the thread.

Comment: Since the port number is all same, command would be;

zcat 2020-07-26-1595751781-https_get_4444.json.gz | jq '.ip' | replace '"' '' > 4444.txt

Thanks again @Hedi-Bejaoui

Comment: @johns2317 Here you go, Sir: `zcat 2020-07-26-1595771130-https_get_50880.json.gz | jq '"\(.ip):\(.port)"' | sed 's/"//g'`. I added the sed command to remove the double quotes surrounding the IPs.

Comment: You can use jq's `-r` option instead of sed.